# Complex defferential equation of order 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve
$$ (u^{IV}+Au''+Bu'+Cu)e^{i\phi}+(Du''+Eu)e^{-i\phi}=0 $$
where $u=u(z)$ is a complex function, and i want equation to hold for all $\phi>0$. But when I separate real and imaginary part, and use the fact that $\sin \phi$ and $\cos \phi$ are linearly independent, i get that 
$$ u_1^{IV}+Au_1''+Bu_1'+Cu_1=0 $$ and
$$ Du_1''+Eu_1=0, $$
where $u_1=\Re (u)$, and the same equations for imaginary part of $u$, $v_1=\Im(u)$. It feels like something is wrong here, any help?

Comment: I have checked, there is nothing wrong, go on.

Comment: Ok thanks, but isn't it obvious now that $u''=-\frac{E}{D}u$, and plugging that into the first equation gives $$u'=\left ( \frac{AE}{BD}-\frac{E^2}{BD^2}-\frac{C}{B} \right )u,$$ so $u=k_1e^{k_2 z}$, with $k_2=\frac{AE}{BD}-\frac{E^2}{BD^2}-\frac{C}{B}$?

Comment: Yes, your computation is fine, everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separate the real and imaginary parts; since you want the equality for all $\phi$, consider $\phi=2\pi$ and $\phi=\pi/2$: so
$$
(u''''+Au''+Bu'+Cu)+(Du''+Eu)=0\\
i(u''''+Au''+Bu'+Cu)-i(Du''+Eu)=0
$$
Divide the second equation by $i$, sum and subtract:
$$
u''''+Au''+Bu'+Cu=0\\
Du''+Eu=0
$$